# Plotting mean and standard deviation for every numeric value in data frame in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I want to plot every numeric column with the mean as a bar and the standard deviation is a line through the bar. How can I do this for the `iris` dataset?

I'm trying to transform my dataset to make it easy to plot in ggplot2.

What I've tried

```
iris %>%
  dplyr::select_if(is.numeric) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(avg_sepal_length = mean(Sepal.Length),
                  avg_sepal_width = mean(Sepal.Width),
                  avg_petal_length = mean(Petal.Length),
                  avg_petal_width = mean(Petal.Width),
                  sd_sepal_length = sd(Sepal.Length),
                  sd_sepal_width = sd(Sepal.Width),
                  sd_petal_length = sd(Petal.Length),
                  sd_petal_width = sd(Petal.Width))
```

I want to pivot into two columns so the dataframe will look like so:

```
stat            mean            sd
sepal_length    5.843333        0.8280661        
sepal_width     3.057333        0.4358663
petal_length    3.758           1.765298    
pedal_width     1.199333        0.7622377
```

And then plot the upperbound and lower bound as a line for the sd and the. mean as a bar in ggplot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your desired result you could first simplify your code using `dplyr::across`. Afterwards you could convert to long via `pivot_longer` whereby using the `.value` allows to put the `mean`s and the `sd`s in their own columns. Finally you could make your plot as a combination of e.g. `geom_col` and `geom_pointrange`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

iris_sum <- iris %>%
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), .fns = list(avg = mean, sd = sd), .names = "{.fn}_{.col}")) |> 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = c(".value", "name"), names_sep = "_") |> 
  mutate(name = gsub("\\.", '_', tolower(name)))

iris_sum
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   name           avg    sd
#>   <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 sepal_length  5.84 0.828
#> 2 sepal_width   3.06 0.436
#> 3 petal_length  3.76 1.77 
#> 4 petal_width   1.20 0.762

ggplot(iris_sum, aes(name, avg)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = avg - sd, ymax = avg + sd))
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! how do I do na.rm = TRUE for the mean and sd functions here? where would i add that?

Comment: In that case we have to be a bit more verbose: `summarise(across(where(is.numeric), .fns = list(avg = ~mean(., na.rm = TRUE), sd = ~sd(., na.rm = TRUE)), .names = "{.fn}_{.col}"))`

Comment: what exactly is the names_to argument doing? what if the column name was originally sepal_length. it would get changed to just sepal. how can i work around that?

Comment: When converting to long `names_to` defines where the column names go to. Here is additionally make use of the special `.value` and `names_sep`. The order in which I used `".value"` and  `"name"` means that for each column (e.g. avg_Sepal.Length) the part before the separator ("_") becomes the name of a new column (e.g. avg) while the second part becomes a category of a new column name. In case your column was named `sepal_length` instead of `Sepal.Length` than we could use the `names_pattern` argument or we could use a different separator with across, e.g. a `.` and then use `names_sep = "."`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply try

```
iris %>%
  dplyr::select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(name, value)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data="mean_sdl", fun.args = list(mult = 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your output format is not the best format for `ggplot2`, which prefers it even longer:

```r
library(tidyr); library(dplyr)

iris %>%
  summarise(
        across(
            where(is.double), 
            list(mean = mean, sd = sd)
        )
    )  |>
    pivot_longer(
        everything(), 
        names_sep = "_", 
        names_to = c("feature", "stat")
    )  


# A tibble: 8 x 3
#   feature      stat  value
#   <chr>        <chr> <dbl>
# 1 Sepal.Length mean  5.84
# 2 Sepal.Length sd    0.828
# 3 Sepal.Width  mean  3.06
# 4 Sepal.Width  sd    0.436
# 5 Petal.Length mean  3.76
# 6 Petal.Length sd    1.77
# 7 Petal.Width  mean  1.20
# 8 Petal.Width  sd    0.762
```

As you are familiar with the `iris` dataset, it is worth checking out the [docs](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html) for `across` which make heavy use of it.

To get to your format you can add the following to the pipe:

```r
|>
    pivot_wider(names_from = "stat")

# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#   feature       mean    sd
#   <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 Sepal.Length  5.84 0.828
# 2 Sepal.Width   3.06 0.436
# 3 Petal.Length  3.76 1.77 
# 4 Petal.Width   1.20 0.762
```

Comment: Or change to: `names_to = c(".value", "name")`

Comment: Then you seem to get the transpose of the table (i.e. `mean` and `sd` are rows). That is cool though - I did not realise you could use `glue` syntax there.

Comment: Sorry, of course: `names_to = c("feature", ".value")` here.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you don't actually need to pre-process the df to calculate the summary values, you can use ggplot2's `stat_summary` directly:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(stack(iris), aes(x = ind, y = values)) + 
  stat_summary(geom = "bar", fun = mean) + 
  stat_summary(
    fun = mean, 
    fun.min = function(x) mean(x) - sd(x), 
    fun.max = function(x) mean(x) + sd(x))
```

Here I've used base R's simple `stack` function to make a long version of the iris dataset; you can use whatever libraries you prefer (especially if you want to include other manipulations).